# split string with adjacent separators

Tags: erlang

I want to split a string with adjacent separators (if you remember the `string:tokens` ignored adjacent separators).

So I have this for now:

```
split(L, C) -> lists:reverse([lists:reverse(X) || X <- split(L, C, [[]])]).

split([], _, Acc) -> Acc;
split([C|T], C, Acc) -> split(T, C, [[]|Acc]);
split([H|T], C, [AH|AT]) -> split(T, C, [[H|AH]|AT]).
```

The return value happens to be `["12432524,,32453,4"]` for the input `tut6:split("12432524,,32453,4", ",").`. I don't understand what the problem is.
Can someone please point it out to me?

The required output is `["12432524", "", "32453", "4"]`

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: You can do this easily with [`re:split/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html#split-3): try `re:split("12432524,,32453,4", ",", [{return,list}]).` in the shell and you'll see that it returns exactly the result you want: `["12432524",[],"32453","4"]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're comparing each character of the string you're splitting to the entire string separator. When you call

```
tut6:split("12432524,,32453,4", ",").
```

then the first invocation of `split/3` inside your module is:

```
split([$1|"2432524,,32453,4"], ",", [[]]) ...
```

The head of the first argument is the *character* `1` but you compare it to the *string* `","`, and of course that will never match and so your input string never gets split.

There are a few ways to fix this:

- Have the caller pass a character separator rather than a string, like this:

  ```
  tut6:split(2432524,,32453,4", $,).
  ```
- Have the caller pass a string separator but use only its first character as the actual separator. You can achieve this by changing `split(L,C)` in your code to either

  ```
  split(L,[C]) ->
      lists:reverse([lists:reverse(X) || X <- split(L, C, [[]])]).
  ```

  to force a single character separator string, or

  ```
  split(L,[C|_]) ->
      lists:reverse([lists:reverse(X) || X <- split(L, C, [[]])]).
  ```

  to use only the first character as the separator and ignore any trailing characters.
- Have the caller pass a string separator and treat each character in the string as a potential separator.
- Have the caller pass a string separator and treat the entire string as a separator.

You can achieve the last of these using [`re:split/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html#split-3):

```
split(L, C) -> re:split(L, C, [{return,list}]).
```

This code isn't fully correct, though, as it works for a simple separator like `","` but won't work in general unless you quote all regular expression metacharacters in the separator string.